# Не в какую ни могу подключиться к базе данных через pdo mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Ошибку вывести почему то не могу, конечно я делаю что то не правильно.

К базе которой я хочу подключится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через этого пользователя подключаюсь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все права доступа есть, раньше все работало.
Как подключаюсь:

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $dbname = DBNAME; //uu13uf1_12
        $dbuser = DBUSER; //root
        $dbpass = DBPASS; //root
        $host = "192.168.1.30";
        try{
            parent::__construct("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

При переходе на страницу выводит мне это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю в чем дело, вроде все ввожу правильно. Все работало, потом для тестирования загрузил свой сайт на хостинг, там так-же есть phpmyadmin, там все работает. Работал с помощи SFTP в Visual Code, после удалил расширение SFTP. Попробовал опять зайти на свой сайт локально и он не работает.
Но я думаю это не из-за этого. Что вы думаете? Какие есть методы?

Comment: "Какие есть методы?" --- ну вот как минимум после fatal error идёт полное описание ошибки, которое можно перевести и проанализировать.........также посмотреть что выдаёт эксепшн......и также перевести в переводчике и проанализировать..........на данный момент текст ошибки не говорит ни о чём

Comment: Также неизвестно что это за класс `PDO`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за ответ! Я не знаю как вывести ошибку. Я использовал try, catch, и все равно не выводит ни каких ошибок. Я тут что то делаю не так.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сейчас тогда попробую и если что то будет то сообщу вам

Comment: вариант 1 - посмотреть в отладчике, вариант 2 - посмотреть в логах......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за толчок. Перед тем как задать вопрос я целый час искал как подключаться. Смирял код, менял браузер, менял пользователей в phpmyadmin, и вы мне сказали вывести ошибку, я сейчас пытался её вывести, и она не выводится. Но удалив весь код то ошибка остается. И как обычно для меня, нужно было проверить не 10 раз а 11. Оказывается Visual Code почему то не обновляет файлы, я её перезагрузил и все стало работать. Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создайте класс с конструктором соединения:

```
class db {  
    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = $this->getDBH('192.168.1.30', $DBNAME, $DBUSER, $DBPASS);
    }

    public function getDBH($host, $dbname, $login, $passwd){
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};", $login, $passwd);
        $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $DBH;
    }
}
```

И потом просто создайте объект этого класса и пользуйтесь его свойством pdo:

```
$db = new db;
$stmt = $db->pdo->prepare("select *...");
```